# Email DF as attachment

Tags: python, pandas

I want to email a Pandas Dataframe as an excel .xlsx attachment. If I save the df as an excel doc via `df.to_excel()`, I'm able to create the attachment with `attachment  = "C:\\Users\\ME\\Documents\\df.xlsx"`. However, I'd like to be able to send the df as a .xlsx without first saving it. Thanks!

```
import win32com.client as win32
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2])

mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'recipient@gmail.com'
mail.Subject = 'See Attachment'
mail.HTMLBody = 'See Attachment'
attachment  = df.to_excel()
mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)
mail.Send()
```

Comment: Is the problem that you don't want to write the file to disk at all? Or that you don't want to write it to your personal Documents directory? If the latter, then consider using a TemporaryFile.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [send email with a pandas dataframe as attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999964/send-email-with-a-pandas-dataframe-as-attachment)

Comment: @BowlingHawk95 I do not want to write it the disk at all. I plan on running this from a server to send out automated emails and don't want to have to deal with creating files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is going to be possible with `win32com`. The Outlook [`Attachments.Add` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/attachments-add-method-outlook) requires a file or an outlook item as the `Source` argument:

> The source of the attachment. This can be a file (represented by the full file system path with a file name) or an Outlook item that constitutes the attachment.

And the `pandas.ExcelWriter` also requires `path` [although this other similar question (and answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999964/send-email-with-a-pandas-dataframe-as-attachment?rq=1) suggest that it may be possible by wrapping `ExcelWriter` in a `BytesIO` to send via email, just not via Outlook:

```
def export_excel(df):
  with io.BytesIO() as buffer:
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(buffer)
    df.to_excel(writer)
    writer.save()
    return buffer.getvalue()
```

But this does not seem work with Outlook API (tested just now):

```
>>> attachment  = export_excel(df)
>>> mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 3, in Add
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147024809, 'The parameter is incorrect.', None, None)
```