# How to send an email with a python data frame as csv or excel attachment?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, dataframe

So I've tried using [send email with a pandas dataframe as attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999964/send-email-with-a-pandas-dataframe-as-attachment) 's answer [Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/1994863/snooze92], which sends the email and has 2 attachments of size 400B and 4.8kB but these can't be opened and have no name.

data frame to html works fine.. I just wanted the attachments to work.

Here's my code pls help thx.

```
def export_csv(df):
  with io.StringIO() as buffer:
    df.to_csv(buffer)
    return buffer.getvalue()

def export_excel(df):
  with io.BytesIO() as buffer:
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(buffer)
    df.to_excel(writer)
    writer.save()
    return buffer.getvalue()

final_df = pd.DataFrame(output, columns=["product", "item_name", "quantity", "address"])
print("Trying to send email.")
EXPORTERS = {store.id+".csv": export_csv, store.id+".xlsx": export_excel}
SEND_FROM = str(se.MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER)
SEND_TO = ["first@email.com", "second@email.com"]
multipart = MIMEMultipart()
multipart['From'] = str(se.MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER_NAME) +"<{}>".format(filename)
multipart['To'] = ",".join(SEND_TO)
multipart['Subject'] = "Daily Orders."
for filename in EXPORTERS:
    attachment = MIMEApplication(EXPORTERS[filename](final_df), Name=filename) # This worked :)
    attachment.add_header('Content-Dispostion', 'attachment', filename="{}".format(filename))
    multipart.attach(attachment)
multipart.attach(MIMEText("Below are {}({})'s collated orders. <br><br>{}".format(store.name, store_id, final_df.to_html()), 'html')) # this works.. I get the data..
print("Added attachments.")
s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(str(se.MAIL_SERVER), int(se.MAIL_PORT))
print("Creating SSL instance.")
s.login(str(se.MAIL_USERNAME), str(se.MAIL_PASSWORD))
print("Logged in. Trying to send.")
s.sendmail(SEND_FROM, SEND_TO, multipart.as_string())
s.quit()
print('Sent.')
```

Comment: (I've got the solution...)Should I delete this post?

Comment: Can you post the answer?